# При создании миграции на обновление выдает ошибку в командной строке проекта (ASP.NET) в виде "Keyword not supported: 'database'."

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, docker, localhost, visual-studio-for-mac

я использую Visual Studio for mac, SQL Server стоит на Docker.
Пробовал много раз изменить строку подключения:

```
    {
          "ConnectionStrings": {
            "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Database=AspCoreCRUDdb;User Id=sa;Password=TheAlexS@1978;"
            //"Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=AspCoreCRUDdb; User=sa; Password=TheAlexS@1978; Integrated Security=True; provider Name=System.Data.SqlClient;"
        }
}
```

но выдает ошибки
[image: Ошибки при разных строках подключения]

Comment: у вас EF Core настроен для Sqlite, а не SQL Server

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ошибка была именно в этом.